# How to do boolean algebra on missing values?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I want to replicate boolean `NA` values as they behave in R:

> NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA & TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE.
>   http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html

I have seen `None` being recommended for missing values, but Python converts `None` to `False` when evaluating boolean expressions, and computes `None or False` to `False`. The result should of course have been `None`, as no conclusions can be made given the missing value.

How do I achieve this in Python?

**EDIT** Accepted answer computes correctly with bitwise boolean operators, but to achieve the same behavior with logical operators `not`, `or` and `and`, seems to require a change in the Python programming language.

Comment: `(lambda x: x | ~x)(NA)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As other have said, you can define your own class.

```
class NA_(object):
    instance = None # Singleton (so `val is NA` will work)
    def __new__(self):
        if NA_.instance is None:
            NA_.instance = super(NA_, self).__new__(self)
        return NA_.instance
    def __str__(self): return "NA"
    def __repr__(self): return "NA_()"
    def __and__(self, other):
        if self is other or other:
            return self
        else:
            return other
    __rand__ = __and__
    def __or__(self, other):
        if self is other or other:
            return other
        else:
            return self
    __ror__ = __or__
    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self
    __rxor__ = __xor__
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other
    __req__ = __eq__
    def __nonzero__(self):
        raise TypeError("bool(NA) is undefined.")
NA = NA_()
```

Use:

```
>>> print NA & NA
NA
>>> print NA & True
NA
>>> print NA & False
False
>>> print NA | True
True
>>> print NA | False
NA
>>> print NA | NA
NA
>>> print NA ^ True
NA
>>> print NA ^ NA
NA
>>> if NA: print 3
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 28, in __nonzero__
TypeError: bool(NA) is undefined.
>>> if NA & False: print 3
...
>>>
>>> if NA | True: print 3
...
3
>>>
```

Comment: I like your answer, but you are still not able to evaluate `NA or True` to `True`? Your examples use bitwise operators..

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible to override "or" and "and". `NA or True` is interpreted as `(NA.__nonzero__() == True) | (True.__nonzero__() == True)`. Please correct me if I'm wrong; I'd love to be wrong about this. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by creating a class and overriding the boolean operation methods.

```
>>> class NA_type(object):
        def __and__(self,other):
                if other == True:
                        return self
                else:
                        return False
        def __str__(self):
                return 'NA'


>>> 
>>> NA = NA_type()
>>> print NA & True
NA
>>> print NA & False
False
```

Comment: `NA & NA` gives `False`. Probably not the desired behavior. Also, it might be good to do something about the fact that `if NA: do_whatever()` executes `do_whatever()` without even a warning.

Comment: @Chris Barker Yes, your answer is much more complete.  I was just giving a jumping-off point.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom class (singleton?) and define custom `__and__` (and whatever other you neeed) function. See this:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types